# Why can the C compiler compile this code even though the C++ compiler can't?

Tags: c++, gcc

In the past,I was taught that the C++ compiler can compile C language code in general except for mixing C and C++ code.
But, I encountered an error that I can't understand in [this code](https://gist.github.com/zonque/0ae2dc8cedbcdbd9b933)

This code can be compiled by the C language compiler of GCC, but the C++ compiler of GCC can't compile this code because of the following error, `44|error: expected unqualified-id before ‘xor’ token|`  in the `crc_update` function.

```
static uint16_t crc_update(uint16_t crc_in, int incr)
{
    uint16_t xor = crc_in >> 15;
    uint16_t out = crc_in << 1;

    if (incr)
        out++;

    if (xor)
        out ^= CRC_POLY;

    return out;
}
```

What caused this error?

Comment: *"I was taught that c++ compiler can compile c language code"* You were taught wrong. C and C++ have been drifting further apart since the beginning of C++.

Comment: C and C++ are **different** languages. Even **iff** code compiles with both compilers, it can have different semantics. Compiling one as the other is a strict **do not**. Wrt the ansers: these are definitively not the only differences. Some are more subtle, others obvious.

Comment: I see,So We must not say inadvertently "I can c/c++".

Comment: That code doesn't look like a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @nonsensickle,thank you for the correction.

Comment: @Lundin Whoops, my bad. Hmm, after fiddling a little more godbolt is probably not the best resource to utilize here so I'll remove my comment.

Comment: If you read some of the comments to other questions you will notice exactly that. `C/C++` is undefined behaviour.

Comment: I would suggest removing the C tag. It's really a C++ question. I don't think people should be getting hung up on that either, since the resolution is simple.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Although very rarely used, `xor` is a [keyword in C++](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword/xor) which can be used as an alternative to `^`. You can't use it as a variable name.

Comment: I appreciate your prompt response. I get it!!

Comment: I would expext that to be in the compiler output...

Comment: @summerbulb: The compiler has no way of knowing that you were trying to use a keyword as a non-keyword. It only knows that you were trying to use a keyword wrong.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: That's not entirely true, the compiler _does_ have a way. When the error is encountered, it could replace the token by a made-up token and see if that resolves the error. This may seem like an exotic approach, but existing compilers already do similar replacements. I.e. many compilers will replace incomplete types in a variable definition with an empty type or `int`. In this case, a compiler that replaced `xor` with `__xor` would find that the error disappears, so it could safely conclude that `keyword xor cannot be used as a variable name`.

Comment: @MSalters: And if I actually intended to use it as a keyword, but got it wrong, and the auto-substitution happens to make the line valid? Then my diagnostic is wrong.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Well, then the diagnostic will be telling you that you used the keyword xor as a variable name (i.e. not as an operator), so the diagnostic is still right. But yes, coming up with good diagnostics is a very hard problem. The biggest problem with my statement IMO is "replace **the** token" - which token? The compiler has a sequence of tokens that fail to compile, but finding the suspect one is non-trivial. Especially here, where the current diagnostic suggests that the compiler **misses** a token before `xor`. That's obviously wrong, since inserting a token doesn't help.

Answer (score 6):

There was some attempt to standardize the names for commonly used operators. Citing the C standard (C11 7.9), these are:

```
and     &&
and_eq  &=
bitand  &
bitor   |
compl   ~
not     !
not_eq  !=
or      ||
or_eq   |=
xor     ^
xor_eq  ^=
```

In C you can use the names in the left column as the equivalent for the corresponding operator, but only if you include `<iso646.h>`. In C++ however, everything from the left column is reserved keywords.

So you should avoid using those as variable names in both C and C++.

See this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_alternative_tokens

Comment: Now why the down vote... I can't find anything wrong in the answer.

Comment: Sorry. I can't understand how  stackoverflow's system behave.

Answer (score 3):

`xor` is a [reserved word](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword) in C++ (but not in C).

Comment: Thanks. I'll be careful of that in future.

Comment: `xor` is not a reserverd word in C, but if you (or a subsequent maintainer) #includes the iso646.h header file, it will be replaced as a macro - so it should probably be avoided anyway.

Comment: @Martin, Thanks for expert tips.